# Get path of a PHAsset coming from CameraRoll iOS with react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm building a video app uploader using react-native.

I encounter a problem with file management from cameraroll. I have video inside my camera roll that i want to either play in my app (using [rn-video](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video)), or upload them.

I tried using [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) with Passtrough option that should not compress video, but i feel like it's copying the video from cameraroll of iOS to AppData. So for big video i'm stuck sometime a longtime on "Processing Asset ..." window (see post [here](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker/issues/1441)).

Now my question is, using [react-native-cameraroll](https://github.com/react-native-cameraroll/react-native-cameraroll), i can fetch directly information about local video, but what i get is a link like this : `ph://EA9508C5-6B69-46EC-8980-832774283946/L0/00`
Is there a way to transform this link into something like this : `'file:///sdcard/Movies/sintel.mp4'` without copying the video entirely into my appData (to avoid long import)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, i found that we can use a different path called `assets-library` in iOS :

`assets-library://asset/asset.${'mov'}?id=${appleId}&ext=${'mov'}`

If you use this path with appleId being the ph asset identificator (something that look like this : `const appleId = 'EFA45A33-818E-4A67-A0D8-50991A9B89FB/L0/001'`  it will work perfectly.

It will work with `react-native-fs //File system for RN` for copy/paste video for example

Comment: I am not sure I understand your solution, please elaborate for me... I am also facing this issue, and this is a snippet of my code.



```
    return CameraRoll.save(videoUri)
      .then(
        (newURI) =>
          new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => { 
            updateLoaderTitle('(2/3) Processing your video')
            console.log('newURI::: ', newURI)
            const videoKey = `pre-inspections/videos/${fileName}.mp4`
            const videoData = await RNFS.readFile(newURI, 'base64')
            const data = videoData.toString('base64') ```

Comment: if you want to fetch without copying, you need to get the appleID after `ph://` and save it somewhere (persistent store for example) using the path : `assets-library://asset/asset.${'mov'}?id=${appleId}&ext=${'mov'}`
If you try to read using this path it will work,otherwise saving with ph:// will not, you'll need to copy the video to your appData to make it work (and my post is for avoiding that)